# I can't get mathptmx to work:

Tags: fonts, texlive, linux, mathptmx

I have wasted one whole working day trying to get `mathptmx` to work. In texmaker I get this error when doing a quick build or pdflatex:

```
! I can't find file `rsfs10'. <*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input
rsfs10 Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...:=ljfour;
mag:=1; nonstopmode; input rsfs10 Transcript written on mfput.log.
```

First I installed the most recent version of texlive with default settings (that thing is huge). Then I fought forever trying to get tlmgr to run. I can finally run that. Then elsewhere on this website, somebody suggested:

```
~$ tlmgr install rsfs
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.uib.no/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

and

```
~$ tlmgr install times
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.uib.no/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

which got me no further. Then I downloaded the `freenfss.zip` and `lw35nfss.zip` from CTAN, and extracted them to both `/etc/texmf` and `/usr/share/texmf`, and it still does not work. There were other directories too, named `texmf`, but I wasn't sure which one to use.

I get the same error over and over again. I have no idea how to proceed, and I have exhausted all of Google for all information which I could though was relevant.

I believe that in the past I installed TeX Live using some apt-get install, but I cannot remember which from the Ubuntu terminal. But today I install it again without removing the previous install using with all the default settings using the unix installer which I found on the TeX Users Group web site: http://www.tug.org/

I hope to get your help to solve the problem.

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using? Is it a TeX Live installed with a package manager on Ubuntu or Fedora?

Comment: I believe that in the past i installed TeX Live using some apt-get install, but I cannot remember which from the Ubuntu terminal. But today I install it again with all the default settings which I found on the TeX Users Group web site: http://www.tug.org/

Comment: You probably just need to put `\usepackage{mathrsfs}` in your document. The `rsfs` font and the latex support in `mathrsfs.sty` are in the full TeX Live already, but the latter is hidden in the `jknapltx` bundle.

Comment: \usepackage{mathrsfs} -> Error: "! Font U/rsfs/m/n/14.4=rsfs10 at 14.4pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found"

Comment: After installing TeX Live from TUG, did you update your paths?  (E.g., what does the command `which latex` return?)  This is crucial: otherwise, your system will continue to use the form of TeX Live installed by `Apt`, which seems to have been the problem in the first place.  Of course, `\usepackage{mathptmx}` should have worked already on the `Apt`-based insall.  So, I wonder, have you been installing font-related stuff on your own before today, and have you been using `updmap` or `updmap-sys` lately?

Comment: @jon ~$ which latex returns: "/usr/bin/latex". which of the tex live versions is this? And if it is incorrect, how can I correct it? In regards to the second part: As far as I can recall I have never messed with the fonts before today, nor used updmap or updmap-sys. Kind regrds,

Comment: Sounds like you haven't set your path after installing TeX Live manually.  I usually set it in `~/.profile`.  See [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html); look at the section "Post-install: setting path".  One thing that this does not do, however, is have `sudo` work well with `tlmgr`; which I work around by using this alias (in, say, `~/.bashrc`): `alias psudo='sudo env PATH="$PATH"'`, and then do `psudo tlmgr <whatever>` rather than `sudo tlmgr <whatever>`.  Remember to `source` your files after you update them (e.g., `source ~/.bashrc`).

Comment: @jon, after setting path, ~$ which latex returns "/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux//latex", but I get the same error when I try to compile in texmaker. What should I check next? Do you reckon it is possible to purge this computer for ever damn trace of software which may be causing problems, and installing it "correctly", somehow? Without reformating the hard-drive? Is there something else I should try?M

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know Texmaker at all, so I can't help with what it may be doing right or wrong.  If you open it from the terminal that shows the new path, maybe it will work..? (Likely only a short-term solution, however.)  You need to verify which TeX installation the program is using: the `Apt`-based one or the freshly installed one.

Comment: I would recommend removing your apt-installed installation of TeX. Only do this *with apt*. Don't just delete the files as that will only create more problems. Also ***never*** manually drop files over directories or files which are maintained by your package manager. Even if it did fix the problem in the short run, it would cause you many more and bigger headaches down the line. (Many more than taking the time to install etc. correctly.) *Safe* places to experiment with packages include `~/texmf` but note that fonts require special installation set up to work. (But *these* are in TL anyway.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.